# Error en fetch anidado

Tags: fetch

tengo el siguiente problema : hago el fetch y los datos dentro del map los trae correctamente, pero al hacer el return es como si no los enviara, los datos del resultado del "map", los guardo en names, si hago console log a names no hay nada, pero antes del return dentro del map, los datos sí están, lo que intento es anidar el fetch de la siguiente manera:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

// const hi = async () => {
//   let responseData
//     const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=1");
//     const data = await response.json();
//     const names = await data.results.map(async (item) => {
//      let urlImages = await fetch(item.url)
//      let dataUrl = await urlImages.json();
//      //console.log(await dataUrl)
//      return dataUrl
//     })
//        console.log('names',names)
//     return await names
//   }

const hi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=1");
  const data = await response.json();

  async function getUrlImages(resp) {
    const res = await resp.results.map(async (item) => {
      const res = await fetch(item.url);
      const data = await res.json();
      //console.log('data',await data); //Hasta aquí todo de maravilla
      return data;
    });
    await console.log("res", await res);
    //aquí afuera res imprime res [ Promise { <pending> } ] y no trae los datos

    return await res;
  }

  //aquí si es que ni logran aparecer porque es el resultado res de getUrlImages
  const urlImages = await getUrlImages(await data);

  return urlImages;
};

hi();
```

La versión comentada es la otra opción que estaba usando. Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

solucioné el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
 async () => {
  let responseData = [];
  let responseUrl = [];

  const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=1");
  const data = await response.json();
  const arr = await data.results;
  return Promise.all(
    arr.map(async (pokemon) => {
      console.log(pokemon)
      const result = await fetchPokemon(pokemon);          
      responseData.push(result);
     
    })

  ).then(() => {
    return {responseData};
  });
}

async function fetchPokemon(pokemon) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`
    );
    return await response.json();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(` problemas al obtener  ${pokemon.name}'s `);
  }
}
```